# how to open api explorer bind with two py files?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Here is my app.yaml

```
    # Endpoints handler
- url: /customer/.*
  script: DimCustomerManagement.APPLICATION

- url: /user.*
  script: DimUserManagement.APPLICATION
```

how to open api explorer to check apis are working or not locally ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://appname.appspot.com/_ah/api
```

If you want to test it on localhost just change the URL to

```
https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=http://localhost:8080/_ah/api
```

Comment: Hi !! Not working. it works if i change url to /.* . But by doing this it works for only one file.

Answer (score 0):

For this explorer will be the same. But there will be two services

create a separate file Suppose 'Services.py'

```
import endpoints
from DimCustomerManagement import name_of_endpoint_classs1
from DimUserManagement import name_of_endpoint_classs2

application = endpoints.api_server([name_of_endpoint_classs1,name_of_endpoint_classs2])
```

change app.yaml

```
# Endpoints handler

- url: /.*
  script: TechHealServices.application
```

Comment: It works on local but not works after deploying project